# Can malware "upload" itself to the actual mobile base station and regain back to another phone?

Tags: malware, mobile, phone, spyware, simcard

My question is can a malware from my affected phone "upload" itself to the **ACTUAL REAL** mobile base station from the service provider, and regain back to my **another** phone with the same number (same identity code), but different SIM card (just same number, same identity)?

My situation: I am using a smartphone with SIM card with mobile internet plan (2GB per month). I know same number from SIM card has same identity code. Is it something like a malware able to spread through over the modem when two computers connected to it? Is it possible? HELP

Comment: There needs to be a vulnerability in the SIM card's firmware or baseband processor's firmware and then also needs to be a vulnerability in the mobile OS's code that talks to the baseband/SIM card to be able to compromise the OS.

Answer (score 3):

Such an attack is theoretically possible, but is it likely? As always, to estimate the risk of an attack you must look at your threat model. Yours doesn't quite make sense.

You are assuming a targeted attack from a sophisticated and well resourced adversary, but that such an adversary wouldn't use a fake base station and directly target your second phone.

(To be fair, you're probably not *consciously* assuming an "ATP" style attack, but the attack you are imagining is too complicated and too specific for anyone else to bother with it.)